# Colour management in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]I am using QGIS on Ubuntu, mainly to create maps for scientific articles. To get reliable colours at the end, I would like to use a colour managed  view inside QGIS. Is there a way to do this, i.e. by specifying an ICC profile, like in other applications such as GIMP or Inkscape?

Edit: As requested, here is a visual example of what I mean by unreliable colors. On the left side is an exported map in a image viewerthat has no support for color management. This is how I see it when working in QGIS. On the right side the very same file is opened in an image viewer with colour management (i.e. how others on average will see it). This is not a technical problem with the screen. High-end wide gamut monitors for graphic designers might show even more disparate colors. This is why most graphic programs offer colour management, not only for content that has to be printed but also for web content.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by "reliable colours"?

Comment: May be you are talking about CMYK support within QGIS. This issue is in discussion and No, QGIS does not support a CMYK colour model yet. see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32754